# USB and PS/2 Keyboard, USB Mouse stopped working after installing 17.04

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, 17.04

I just installed 17.04 on my desktop and am unable to use the USB keyboard. The keyboard works at the BIOS level, but stops working once the screen turns purple (the NumLock light turns off). I have tried booting from CD (the mouse works, but still no keyboard), trying every USB port on the device (again, the mouse works on a couple of ports (both 2.0 and 3.0) but no keyboard), and changing settings in my BIOS. I can't get into grub because of the lack of keyboard.

EDITED: I have a PS/2 keyboard now and I reinstalled 16.04, and everything works fine there. I'm trying to fix 17.04 in recovery mode with little luck.
I turned on autologin, but now the mouse doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you have other USB devices, besides the mouse & keyboard plugged in? Do you have another mouse & keyboard to try?

Comment: I don't have anything plugged in besides the mouse and keyboard. I just plugged in a PS/2 keyboard which works when I boot from CD into 16.04 but not when i'm in 17.04.

Comment: Is there a USB setting in your BIOS for legacy? What are the choices there? Is your keyboard a PS/2 keyboard with a USB adapter? That may be a problem.

Comment: ps: Try plugging the PS/2 keyboard into the PS/2 keyboard port.

Comment: The PS/2 keyboard is in the PS/2 port.

Comment: I turned off Legacy in my BIOS options (enabled - DISABLED - auto) and still nothing.

Comment: oh, is that where the keyboard always was... in the PS/2 port? Add a PS/2 to USB adapter and plug it into a USB port and see if it works. Set the BIOS USB setting back.

Comment: The keyboard was a USB keyboard that I traded for a PS/2 keyboard. I don't have a USB adaptor (or the USB keyboard right now)

Comment: A local computer store will probably give you the adapter. You need to edit your subject, and your text, to change "USB keyboard stopped working..." as it's a PS/2 keyboard.